# asp.net Web API most efficient way to replace a request response body to have a consistant error structure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, owin

I am using as Web API what uses `AuthorisationManager` owin middleware to handle token based security.

My problem is that various errors within the response body have various different formats.

Within my api, I usually send errors back with the structure

```
 {"code": "error code", "message": "error message"}
```

However some of the errors coming from the security may use

```
 {"error": "error code", "error_description": "error message"}
```

or sometimes just

```
 {"error": "error mesage"}
```

I would like to unify these to all have the same structure I use elsewhere, ie the

```
{"code": "error code", "message": "error message"}
```

I have seen quite a few posts on replacing a response body.

I first tried [this method](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/wrapping-asp.net-web-api-responses-for-consistency-and-to-provide-additional-information), ie using the `DelegatingHandler`. This worked in most cases, but it did not catch my authorization failed error messages comding out of my `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider`

I next tried using a middleware approach as [shown here](http://mitzen.blogspot.com/2016/12/owin-component-modifying-owin-response.html).

Here is my full interpretation..

```
    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
      try
      {
        // hold a reference to what will be the outbound/processed response stream object
        var stream = context.Response.Body;        

        // create a stream that will be sent to the response stream before processing
        using (var buffer = new MemoryStream())
        {
          // set the response stream to the buffer to hold the unaltered response
          context.Response.Body = buffer;

          // allow other middleware to respond
          await this.Next.Invoke(context);

          // Error codes start at 400. If we have no errors, no more to d0.
          if (context.Response.StatusCode < 400) // <---- *** COMMENT1 ***
            return;

          // we have the unaltered response, go to start
          buffer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

          // read the stream
          var reader = new StreamReader(buffer);
          string responseBody = reader.ReadToEnd();

          // If no response body, nothing to do
          if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseBody))
            return;

          // If we have the correct error fields names, no more to do
          JObject responseBodyJson = JObject.Parse(responseBody);
          if (responseBodyJson.ContainsKey("code") && responseBodyJson.ContainsKey("message"))
            return;

          // Now we will look for the known error formats that we want to replace...
          byte[] byteArray = null;

          // The first one from the security module, errors come back as {error, error_description}.
          // The contents are what we set (so are correct), we just want the fields names to be the standard {code, message}
          var securityErrorDescription = responseBodyJson.GetValue("error_description");
          var securityErrorCode = responseBodyJson.GetValue("error");
          if (securityErrorDescription != null && securityErrorCode != null)
            byteArray = CreateErrorObject(securityErrorCode.ToString(), securityErrorDescription.ToString());

          // The next horrible format, is when a refresh token is just sends back an object with 'error'.
          var refreshTokenError = responseBodyJson.GetValue("error");
          if (refreshTokenError != null)
          {
            // We will give this our own error code
            var error = m_resourceProvider.GetRefreshTokenAuthorisationError(refreshTokenError.ToString());
            byteArray = CreateErrorObject(error.Item2, error.Item3);
          }
          else
          {
            byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(responseBody);
          }

          // Now replace the response (body) with our now contents

          // <---- *** COMMENT2 ***
          context.Response.ContentType = "application / json";          
          context.Response.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
          buffer.SetLength(0);
          buffer.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
          buffer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
          buffer.CopyTo(stream);
        }
      }     
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        m_logger.WriteError($"ResponseFormattingMiddleware {ex}");
        context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
        throw;
      }      
    }

     private byte[] CreateErrorObject(string code, string message)
        {
          JObject newMessage = new JObject();
          newMessage["code"] = code;
          newMessage["message"] = message;
          return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(newMessage.ToString());      
        }
```

So this basically seemed to work, and catch ALL responses, which is good.

However, what I was hoping to do, is, when there is no error, (or the error is already in the correct format), just pass the response on without doing anything with it.

I am mainly thinking of some of my GETs, where the data may be large, I was hoping to avoid having to do the extra copying back. In the above code, where I have marked `*** COMMENT1 ***`, I have an early return to try to avoid this, ie the line...

```
    // Error codes start at 400. If we have no errors, no more to d0.
    if (context.Response.StatusCode < 400)
        return;
```

The problem, is when I do this, I get no body at all returned, ie no data for all the GET calls, etc.

Is there a way to avoid this extra copying (ie at the line `*** COMMENT2 ***`) when we don't want to do any modifications?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Aren't you emptying the response here `context.Response.Body = buffer;`.

Comment: To make it more clear: You are instantiating a new empty memorystream `using (var buffer = new MemoryStream())`. So even this line wouldn't make much sense as it is still empty at that point `buffer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`

Comment: To do this, I basically copied the sample code, and I must admit, I find it a bit hard to understand what is going on there; it does look a little hacky to me. The `delegatingHandler` seems like the "more correct" approach, but it just does not seem to catch all responses. Very frustrating for what I thought would be a common task someone would want to do (ie have a common error response format).

Answer (score 1):

Adding an answer since it has a code snippet but this is really just a comment.

Our services use the delegatingHandler approach you mentioned you tried first.  Do you have try/catch around the call to `base.SendAsync`.  In this snippet the `requestState` is just a wrapper around the incoming request with some timers, loggers, etc.  In many cases we replace the response as you are trying.  I stepped through the exception and used the VS debugger immediate window to modify the error response. It works for me.`(TM)`

```
        try
        {
            return base
                .SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
                .ContinueWith(
                    (task, requestState) => ((InstrumentedRequest)requestState).End(task),
                    instrumentedRequest,
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
                    TaskScheduler.Default)
                .Unwrap();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            instrumentedRequest.PrematureFault(ex);
            throw;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for that.I put in an exception handler, but it is not entered either in the case where I call `context.SetError("MyErrorCode", "My error message")` from my overridden `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider.GrantResourceOwnerCredentials`. Almost everything else does enter than handler, but not in this case